# Evaluate this trig limit without L'Hospital: $\lim_{x\to\ 0}\;x\tan\left(\frac{\pi\left(1-x\right)}{2}\right)$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

> $$\lim_{x\to\ 0}\;x \tan\left(\dfrac{{\pi}\left(1-x\right)}{2}\right)$$

How do you do this without L'Hospital's Rule?

The result is supposed to be $\dfrac{2}{{\pi}}$.

Comment: There are all kinds of sum formulas to try.

Answer (score 0):

[Using some trig identities](https://www.google.com/search?q=tan(pi/2-theta)&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=894&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjC3--EsK7QAhXEOCYKHe1iCAkQ_AUIBygC), we have

$$\begin{align}x\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi x}2\right)&=x\cot\left(\frac{\pi x}2\right)\\&=x\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}2\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}2\right)}\\&=\frac2\pi\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}2\right)\left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}2\right)}{\frac{\pi x}2}\right)^{-1}\end{align}$$

And recall how to do limits of the form $\displaystyle\frac{\sin(u)}u.$

Answer (score 0):

For the limit itself, you already received the answer from Simple Art.

If you want to go further and to know how the limit is approched, consider $$A=x\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi x}2\right)=x\cot\left(\frac{\pi x}2\right)=\frac 2 \pi \frac {\frac{\pi x}2} {\tan(\frac{\pi x}2)}$$ Now, remembering the Taylor series $$\tan(y)=y+\frac{y^3}{3}+O\left(y^5\right)$$ then $$\frac y{\tan(y)}=\frac 1 {1+\frac{y^2}{3}+O\left(y^4\right)}=1-\frac{y^2}{3}+O\left(y^4\right)$$ Replace $y$ by $\frac{\pi x}2$ and get $$A=\frac{2}{\pi }-\frac{\pi  x^2}{6}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ Just for the fun, plot the function and the approximation for $-\frac 12 \leq x \leq \frac 12$.